# Why is my code failing the JUnit testing for IllegalArgumentException?

Tags: java

I was asked to implement a method called setLevel. I also needed to throw an IllegalArgumentException() between MIN and MAX values which I had grabbed from a previous class called Hounsfield. This is connected to a JUnit tester and I passed most of the tests except for the test that I posted below and I do not understand why. The first block of code is mine and the second block is the code for the failing JUnit test. Specifically the line failing is "fail(String.format("new HounsfieldWindow(%s, 10) should throw an exception", level))".

edit: I have added all of my code up to the setLevel method as well.

```
public class HounsfieldWindow {
private int level, width;

public HounsfieldWindow(int level, int width) {
    this.level = level;
    this.width = width;
}

public HounsfieldWindow() {
    this(0, 400); 
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public int setLevel(int level) {
    if (level < Hounsfield.MIN_VALUE || level > Hounsfield.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int data = this.level;
    this.level = level;
    return data;
}


@Test
public void test04_ctorThrowsOnBadLevel() {
    final int[] BAD_LEVELS = { -10000, -1025, 3072, 9999 };
    for (int level : BAD_LEVELS) {
        try {
            new HounsfieldWindow(level, 10);
            fail(String.format("new HounsfieldWindow(%s, 10) should throw an exception", level));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException x) {
            // ok
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are `Hounsfield.MIN_VALUE` and `Hounsfield.MAX_VALUE`? And where is `setLevel` being called?

Comment: Consider using step-by-step debugging to solve this. Put a checkpoint on your method call in the problematic JUnit test, launch the JUnit test in debug mode, you'll be able to check if the parameter your function receives is the expected one, if the `Hounsfield.X_VALUES` are properly set, how the condition is evaluated, etc.

Comment: Actually, nothing in the JUnit test directly calls your `setLevel` method. Does the `HounsfieldWindow(int, int)` constructor do? Have you checked there isn't a bug there?

Comment: Note that JUnit 5 (and later versions of 4) have the `assertThrows` method, which is neater than try/fail: `assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new HounsfieldWindow(level, 10))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your unit test is not actually testing the method you claim it is. It looks like your constructor should actually be calling the set level method. As it stands right now, the constructor can set the level outside the acceptable parameters defined within the set level method which does not appear to be what you desire.

The following change to your constructor should fix your test.

```java
public HounsfieldWindow(int level, int width) {
    setLevel(level);
    this.width = width;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) [don't forget to accept the answer so this issue is closed]

Answer (score -1):

You must put fail statement in catch block

Comment: The OP wants the test to pass when they get an exception.

Comment: You can always put expected on the annotation

Comment: Good advice, but this doesn't answer the question. (This answer is misinformative and will make their tests fail 100% of the time)

Comment: @Test
public void testFooThrowsIndexOutOfBoundsException() {
  boolean thrown = false;

  try {
    foo.doStuff();
  } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    thrown = true;
  }

  assertTrue(thrown);
}